# Order a django queryset by 2 criteria

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a django model that has two fields among others

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    #other fields
    date = models.DateField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I want to retrie all user models order them by user alphabetically and then order them by date ascending. Will this do?

```
entries = Entry.objects.all().order_by('user').order_by('date')
```

But I don't think this is the case. The result of the above command is entries ordered_by date but not by user (cause the order_by('date') was called last in the chain). Correct? How can I order a queryset using to criteria?

Answer (score 4):

If you want users alphabetically you must sort by user name not id, like:

```
Entry.objects.order_by('user__first_name', 'date')
```

Comment: didn't know that order_by can take two arguments or more. This will order alphabetically keep order and then by date?So it would be all entries with first_name starting by a first but with entries ordered chronologically etc?